# Android: implement auto-updates for my apps?

Tags: android

I would like auto-updates to be enabled for my application.  After lots of searching, I can not find any information about how to implements this.  My interpretation is that it is a feature of 2.2 and android marketplace, and will happen automatically.  However, I have a few questions about this that I cannot find answers to on Google:

1. How does this work?  Do I just publish a new version to the Google marketplace and then users are prompted to update their application?  If so, is there a way to control if I want to allow the user to be able to update? (like, if I publish 1.1, I would like to allow an update. but not for 2.0).
2. Do I need to specify anything in my manifest file or anywhere else in my app?
3. If this is a 2.2 feature, will it work if my app is 2.1 compliant? (I assume it would not work for users running 2.1, but want to make sure being 2.1 compliant would not break it).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. just publish a new version and users will be prompted to install.   i think for preventing updates to v2 you will need to create a new app (or change the properties so google thinks its  a new app
2. you will need to increment your android:versionCode="??" in the manifest
3. you will have to specify the minSdkversion and if you use a newer feature than is available in an older version your app 'supports', you will have to check the version they are running and disable the feature or code it someother way.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong here but I believe auto update is a function that the user would control. The user has the option to allow your app to auto update from the android market place provided the permissions have not changed. I do not think you can force the user to auto update.

Answer (score 1):

You can control auto updates by opening the "market" When the 'Market" home screen is open, click the "menu" button( lower far left on your device.) a settings menu will pop up and you can set the auto-update features there...